# How can I test the mouse right button drag?

Tags: c#, winforms

This test the mouse right button click.
But now I want to test when I click and hold down the right mouse button and also drag the mouse around.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Mouse_Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int numClicks = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            label1.Text = "0";
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                numClicks++;
                label1.Text = numClicks.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For example draw a line on the form1 only when holding down the right mouse button and dragging the mouse around.

[image: Clicks test and now I want to add the dragging test]

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561755/attempting-to-simulate-mouse-click-drag).

Answer (score 0):

This is a working solution like I wanted for testing. It seems like when holding down the right mouse button and dragging the mouse it's not working almost at all not drawing. But if I'm holding down the left mouse button and dragging the mouse it's drawing smooth. So the problem is the mouse right button.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Mouse_Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ArrayList listOfPoints;
        bool PencilDown;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            listOfPoints = new ArrayList();
            PencilDown = false;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left || e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                Point p = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
                listOfPoints.Add(p);
                PencilDown = true;
                this.statusStrip1.Items[0].Text = "MouseDown";
            }
        }

        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
            Point points = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            Pen pencil = new Pen(Color.White);

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                pencil = new Pen(Color.BlueViolet);
            }

            if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                pencil = new Pen(Color.Red);
            }

            if(PencilDown)
            {
                this.statusStrip1.Items[0].Text = "MouseMove";
                if(listOfPoints.Count > 1)
                {
                    g.DrawLine(pencil, (Point)listOfPoints[listOfPoints.Count - 1], points);
                }
                listOfPoints.Add(points);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            PencilDown = false;
            this.statusStrip1.Items[0].Text = "MouseUp";
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```